# Is it possible to use "and", "or" "not" as relation/predicate in an ontology? In order to represent causality?

Tags: computer-science, ontology, causality, knowledge-graph

If we use an ontology we can represent many things using `<s,p,o>` semantic triple.

I was wondering how can I represent this:

A and B cause C

or

A or B cause C

?

I don't want to do reasoning, I only want to represent.

Is it possible to use and, or, negation as predicate/relation in an ontology?

Conjunction, disjunction and implication have a proper logical meaning.

I only see that researchers use causal networks to represent causality, but I was wondering why it is not possible in an ontology.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: What about (A and B and C) and not (A and B and (not C))? Does that convey the meaning you're going for?

Comment: @Patrick87 thanks for your answer. Conjunction, disjunction and implication have a proper meaning. You can't change these statement to this. I am looking for an argument saying that it is not possible the represent causality in ontologies, but i may miss something. I found nothing.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to represent, and not reason with, the sentences or formulas you wrote, then you just need to find an *encoding*. Any encoding that you can parse back into the original sentences would work. As an example, here is a suggestion.

Consider your two examples:

```
A and B cause C
A or B cause C
```

In both cases, you can split the sentence into 3 parts:

```
something  causes  something
```

This is a triple! Let us make an IRI for the predicate "causes": `http://example.com/causes`, abbreviated `ex:causes`. The second "something" on the right-hand side is C in the examples. Let us identify it with `ex:C`. The remain part, the first "something" on the left-hand side is more complicated, because we need to encode that it is a compound structure. In the first case, it is a something that is a conjunction that has components A and B. This can be encoded as a blank node with type `ex:Conjunction` (for instance) and two triples that connect it to `ex:A` and `ex:B` (for instance). Then, in Turtle syntax, we could have:

```
[
    a  ex:Conjunction;
    ex:component  ex:A, ex:B
]  ex:causes  ex:C .
```

or:

```
[
    a  ex:Disjunction;
    ex:component  ex:A, ex:B
]  ex:causes  ex:C .
```

If you need something more complicated, such as:

```
(A and B) or (C and D and E) causes (F or (G and H))
```

you can write:

```
[
    a  ex:Disjunction;
    ex:component  [
        a  ex:Conjunction;
        ex:component  ex:A, ex:B
    ], [
        a  ex:Conjunction;
        ex:component  ex:C, ex:D, ex:E
    ]
]  ex:causes  [
    a  ex:Disjunction;
    ex:component  ex:F, [
        a  ex:Conjunction;
        ex:component  ex:G, ex:H
    ]
] .
```

etc. There is no way to express causality in the semantics of RDF or OWL. So you would have to parse this and translate it into a logic of causality if you want to make interesting inferences. In that sense, the RDF representation is not much more "semantic" than, say, an XML or JSON encoding. The only (important) difference with and XML or JSON encoding is that you use IRI for everything, which allows you to formally attach more information to every components, in a distributed, modular and hypermedia way.